# Finding minimum of a two variable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

> Let $D=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:1\le x\le1000,1\le y\le1000\}$. Define
>   $$f(x,y)={xy\over2}+{500\over x}+{500\over y}$$
>   Then the minimum value of $f$ on $D$ is

Finding $f_x=\frac y2-{1000\over x^2},f_y=\frac x2-{1000\over y^2}$, and solving, $f_x=0=f_y$, I am left with $\frac y2\times {1000\over y^2}=\frac x2\times{1000\over x^2}\implies x=y$. Using it we get $x=y=10\sqrt[3]2$

Now finding second partial derivatives and finding $f_{xx},f_{xx}f_{yy}-f^2_{xy}$ confirms that it is a minimum.

$f(10\sqrt[3]2,10\sqrt[3]2)\approx158$ (I used a calculator to check - I am not allowed tto in exam), but initially when I by trial and error I had found $f(10,10)=150$ which is lower than the minimum found.

What am I missing/where did I go wrong?

Comment: The min value is in fact $150$.  Easiest way is AM-GM.

Comment: You went wrong differentiating $500/x$. Should get $-500/x^2$. Same error with $500/y$.

Comment: @Andre: Thanks! Mixed differentiation up with integration! And I was not aware of AM-GM method (haven't done any coursework on minimization)! Learning!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are aware of the famous Cauchy inequality, you would solve it in a couple of seconds....Here we go: $f(x,y) \geq 3\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{xy}{2}\cdot \dfrac{500}{x}\cdot \dfrac{500}{y}}= 150$, and equality occurs at $x = y = 10$.

Comment: This is AM-GM, not Cauchy (there are no cube roots, or raised to the third power in Cauchy, only squares). Still, nice solution.